# How can I test that a value in a list isn't found with .index() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv where there are a wide range of streets that can be repeated. I want to create a list where I have only a value of the streets that appear, without any repetition. Here is a better example if I haven't explained myself:

.csv contents -> "street1","street2","street1", "street1", "street3", "street2"

list I want to make -> "street1", "street2", "street3"

This is the code I have:

```
def differentStreets():
    streets = ["example"]
    
    with open("streetsCSV.csv", mode="r", newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_reader:
            if(streets.index(row[8])>=0):
                continue
            else:
                streets.append(row[8])
```

(row[8] is the column where the values of the streets are found)

As you can see, I have using the .index() function for lists. My idea was to use it and if the index given was 0 or more, it would mean the street has already been added to the list that should be returned, therefore it should continue. If it doesn't return a value, then the street name is added to the list I created. The problem is that when I run the program, an error appears: "ValueError: 'LINCOLN TUNNEL E SOUTH TUBE - NJ - NY' is not in list". I have been looking for documentation for the .index() function but all resources I find doesn't specify what to do if I am trying to work with a value that is not found in the list.

I would like to know how I can work with the function to make it work, or if there is another method I can do to come up with a solution to the program.

Thank you.

Comment: You could wrap the call to `streets.index` in a try-catch block, but that's silly. Instead, you should be using `if row[8] in streets:` to simply check for membership. Since that's all you're doing with `streets` anyway, a `set` would be more appropriate than a `list`. Infact, using a `set` would eliminate the entire for-loop: `streets = set(map(lambda row: row[8], csv_reader))`. A `set` will not preserve the insertion-order of its elements, however.

Comment: You can use `try: ... except:` to handle the error. But @PaulM.'s comment is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try` and `except` as others have already mentioned, as `mylist.index(value)` raises ValueError if the given value is not an element of the list.

Another slightly simpler solution is:

```
if value in mylist: 
    i = mylist.index(value)
```

The if statement makes sure that the value is present in the list so you dont run into a ValueError.